# Error: Cannot change attributes of configuration ':android:kapt' after it has been resolved when update Android Studio to 3.2

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin, libgdx, kapt

Today I updated Android Studio to 3.2 and got this error:

```
Cannot change attributes of configuration ':android:kapt' after it has been resolved
```

I've tried searching a few similar errors to "cannot change attritubtes of configuration...after it has been resovled" out there but none of them worked for me.

I have configureOnDemand set to false in gradle.properties and both of my repositories blocks look like this:

```
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
jcenter()
google()
```

Update: I narrowed it down to the cause of updating build gradle to 3.2. So I will have to use 3.1 for now.

Comment: please post your `build.gradle` file

Comment: Here's my root gradle: https://codeshare.io/a30jWz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see you've problem in your LibGDX project *(From your attached `build.gradle` file)*

---

> Cannot change attributes of configuration ':android:kapt' after it has
>   been resolved.

is an [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5387) that has been resolved by detaching native task by [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/2a429a82463ed6dc2e24219f9ac67328789c8f43) commit.

Solution :

1. If you're going to create new project use [latest build](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/) of LibGDX `1.9.8`
2. Else make required changes in android `build.gradle` file (For reference you can use [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/2a429a82463ed6dc2e24219f9ac67328789c8f43#diff-8a8e3e080f70930b28628d291b8d76b7))

Comment: It just solved it, I'm able to use 3.2.1 and its full features now. Thank you